# Retrieve Full Content of Posts from RSS Feed

Tags: c#, rss

I'm trying to use code to read my WordPress blog's RSS feed ([here](https://rardk.com/blog/feed/)) and extract the content of each post. I've read elsewhere that the feed doesn't include the full content, but when I open that link, I see the full content of the posts in the `content:encoded` element. I'm looking to extract that content.

Here's what I'm trying now:

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create(blogSettings.RssFeedUrl);
var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
var items = feed.Items.Select(i =>
{
    var contentEncoded = i.ElementExtensions
        .ReadElementExtensions<string>("encoded", "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content");
    return new BlogPost
    {
      // TODO
    };
});
return items;
```

However, the `contentEncoded` here ended up empty. Is there a way to extract this content?

Comment: Just fix that xml namespace to `http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/`, notice the trailing slash.

Comment: that did it! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

pfx answered in the comments above, the fix here was to correct the namespace I had to include the trailing slash, like so: `http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/`